# Not able to use internet after setting the proxy to manual on my android phone

Tags: jmeter, performance

I am testing my native mobile app with JMeter; for that, I am using IP on my PC to my Android phone where my app is. Then I record the whole script and play it in JMeter. I have installed all the certificates.

But after changing the proxy on mobile to Manual and giving the proxy hostname as My PC's IP, it still is not working.

Comment: Sorry I have the same problem, which IP to use as proxy IP in the mobile ? I used my laptop's ip where jmeter is installed and recording but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your JMeter, network and Android configuration, the "good" steps are:

1. Make sure the host running JMeter and Android device are on the same subnet
2. Make sure that cellular data is disabled
3. Make sure firewall is not blocking incoming connections to port 8888
4. Start JMeter's proxy:

   - from JMeter's main menu choose File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
   - expand [Workbench](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#WorkBench) -> [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start"
5. Configure your Android device to use the PC running JMeter as a proxy (use IP address as proxy host and `8888` as proxy port)
6. If your application is using HTTPS traffic:

   - install `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` certificate onto Android device. Make sure you have "fresh" certificate as it has limited lifetime (7 days), if the certificate is older - just delete it and restart JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - it will generate a new one
   - Depending on your Android vendor/version you might have to use a 3rd-party tool like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) in order to send HTTPS traffic via proxy
7. If above steps won't help (unlikely thought) be aware that there is an alternative way of recording native mobile applications network events. As a bonus you will get automated correlation of any dynamic parameters. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply I have done all the things which you have told except One
My android device(0.0.0.0)  and my PC (255.255.255.0)  are on the different Subnets 
I  have searched entire net but didn't found how to make those on the same Subnet

Comment: and one more question I have it may interest you
When I am recording my script in GUI mode , Can I run that script in Non-GUI , as this is testing for Native Application not any web-application

Comment: 1. For putting both devices under the same subnet - make sure you switch ["IP Settings" from "DHCP" to "Static"](https://it.uoregon.edu/node/3559), after that you will be able to manually specify IP address and network mask 

2. For running tests in non-GUI mode: definitely yes, moreover this is the recommended way of executing a JMeter test as GUI is very resource intensive. See [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) for details.

Comment: 1. Put mine PC's IP in Proxy Host name for android and port be the same as on Jmeter  
2. Changed from DHCP to Static and put the IP as the IP of my Computer and default gateway seen on my command prompt 
But still the net doesn't work  so will not be able to load scripts.
any suggestions on this.

Comment: Don't put IP of your computer as IP of your Android device, duplicate IPs are not allowed, one of them will not work, choose a free IP address from the same subnet and assign that IP to the Android device

Comment: So in The Proxy Host Name I have put my PCs IP and for port as the same on JMeter 
For the Static IP I have put other system's  IP  on the same subnet
Still no internet Connection

Comment: Oh its working problem was with the  other IP's  internet Connection